# Set line endings on a specific file within my local repository

Tags: git

We have a file in our repository that has `crlf` line endigs. However in my local environment I would like to have `lf` line endigs in that file. Is there a way to do that?

I found some information about configuration file [.gitattributes](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings) but using this configuration file IMHO I can set line endings for a particular files within the repository. Moreover this file should be commited to the repository and therefore used by all users. I don't want to force other users to checkout this file with `lf` line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found some information about configuration file .gitattributes but using this configuration file IMHO I can set line endings for a particular files within the repository.

I don't know what you mean.  Yes, attributes (in particular the `text` and `eol` attributes) can be used to set line endings for a file; that's not a matter of opinion.

> Moreover this file should be commited to the repository and therefore used by all users. I don't want to force other users to checkout this file with lf line endings.

Attributes that should not be checked in are placed in `.git/info/attributes` (just as ignore rules that should not be checked in are placed in `.git/info/excludes`)

Comment: I did put _attributes_ file in .git/info folder with content set to `task text eol=lf` where _task_ is name of the file I would like to use with `lf` line endings, but when I try change line endings in the _task_ file to `lf` and run git status it still tells me the file _task_ is modified.

Comment: @Behnil: Changes in the worktree are detected by comparing stat info. If you manually change the line endings, the stat info won't match, and the file will appear to have changed.  I would expect if you `git add` the file, ti will no longer be shown as changed (and will also not show up as a staged change); but I'd say the "right" way to handle it is to delete and re-checkout the file (as the checkout is when line ending filters are applied).